# openssl_pkey_new returns blank with no error message

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
    $config = array(
    "digest_alg" => "sha512",
    "private_key_bits" => $size,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
    "config" => "/home/user/openssl/ssl/openssl.cnf"
);  
    // Create the private and public key
    echo "hi";
    debug_to_console($config);
    $res = openssl_pkey_new($config);
    debug_to_console($res);
    while ($msg = openssl_error_string()){
            echo $msg . "<br />\n";
    }


    // Extract the private key from $res to $privKey
    openssl_pkey_export($res, $privKey);
    // Extract the public key from $res to $pubKey
    $pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
    $pubKey = $pubKey["key"];

    echo "hello";
    var_dump($pubKey);
    var_dump($privKey);
    return $pubKey;
```

For some reason, `openssl_pkey_new` does not return anything at all - not even an error.

"hi" prints out, and `debug_to_console` just outputs the values to the console. `$config` is printed fine, but anything after the `$res` line is blank. The entire page is just "hi" and nothing else.

I'm quite confused how its not working and theres no error message.. anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:
On archlinux, PHP 5.5.9

Comment: "Returns a resource identifier for the pkey on success, or FALSE on error." Is "sha512" a valid entry? What is `$size`?

Comment: $size is 2048. even if i try without sha512, it doesnt work. it doesnt return False at all @miken32

Comment: Yes, it is returning false, and it's because one of your values in `$config` is incorrect.

Comment: If its returning false, why dont I see it in the console with the $debug_to_console? i tried to echo $res as well @miken32

Comment: You can't `echo` a boolean false value. `echo` is for strings.

Comment: Try `var_dump()`, it’ll return more useful info...

Comment: Even then, it didnt debug anything to the console. openssl_error_string did not print anything as well @miken32

Comment: Maybe add more specifics to your question (eg. php version, platform/os, any relative logs, etc.)

Comment: @l'L'l var_dump $res does nothing as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php